# ORA-04045: errors during recompilation/revalidation

Tags: oracle

I just suddenly started getting this error when trying to query the table AVC.

```
ORA-04045: errors during recompilation/revalidation of PUBLIC.AVC
ORA-04098: trigger 'TTMS.ALTERED_TTMSDB_TABS_TRIGGER' is invalid and failed re-validation
```

`select * from avc` doesnt work
but `select * from exfc.avc` does work.

Can anyone tell me what is going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably there is not an object in your schema named `AVC`.  When you reference `AVC` without a schema qualifier, it is therefore accessing the `PUBLIC` object with that name.  To find out what kind of object that is, `SELECT object_type FROM all_objects WHERE object_name='AVC' AND owner='PUBLIC'`.

Whatever it is, querying it is for some reason causing a trigger to fire.  Maybe this is some sort of auditing function.  But currently the trigger is invalid.  This could mean that someone modified the trigger itself but made an error; or it could mean that someone dropped or modified some other object that the trigger depends on, in such a way that the trigger code is no longer valid.

So, whoever's responsible for that trigger needs to find out what error is occurring in its compilation and resolve it.

When you explicitly query `EXFC.AVC`, you are bypassing the `PUBLIC` object and going directly to some underlying object, probably an actual table.  It seems very odd that you would have access to this, since the whole point of routing access through a public synonym is usually to prevent direct access to the object.  And if, in fact, the purpose of the trigger is to audit accesses to the table, then allowing you to bypass it entirely is a pretty big design flaw.

Comment: +1, but this nit pick is required: a public synonym cannot "prevent direct access" to anything, it's just a way to avoid hardcoding schema names in code, or to allow referring to something but use a different name.

Comment: Hi, I'm getting the same issues but with a PACKAGEnot executed, package body "<PACKAGE>.RDSADMIN" does not exist, I presume dropping this would do the same thing?

Comment: @Casper I don't understand how your comment relates to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it basically tells you that the trigger mentioned has an error. Easiest way I could fix this since I was working on SQL developer was,

Open up 'Triggers' tab and search for this trigger. Compile it and run your query again. works perfectly fine :)